# Mongoose response handling

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My goal is:

- response if there is a connection error with mongodb,
- response if user does not exists,
- response if user exists

This is my code so far. I am using some custom response functions which return rich messages within my API.

```
.get(function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user) {
    if(err) res.send(err);

    if(!user) {
      res.status(404).json(notFoundResponse_404(user))
    }
    else {
      res.status(200).json(showResponse_200(user));
    }
  });
})
```

My problem is that err gets triggered before !user. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: Because I want to show my own message "User not found" instead of mongoDB error.

Comment: If there's a mongo error how do you know it's actually a 404? If there's a mongo error they will all be 404s. If that's the case why even bother sending a response for `err`? Just log something instead.

Comment: Well, if there is no user, err gets triggered. Instead of !user. I don't want to omit err handling cause there will be other situations.

Comment: In the case where your query can't find a user and `!user` is true, what is `err`? Not finding a user should not result in `err` being true. The only other difference between this and similar code in my projects are `return`s in front of `res.send`.

Comment: The err is "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value...

Comment: Which means that `req.params.user_id` is not a valid ObjectId for Mongo. Your query is breaking and the code is behaving appropriately.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Now I am getting into !user error.